# In C#, How can I make the user's input of one text field appear in a string on another text field without overwriting the current content?

Tags: c#, asp.net

I need the user input to appear after the word 'assigned'. I tried:

```
$(document).ready(function() 
{
   $('#txtInstructions').keyup(function (e) {
                var txtVal = $(this).val();
                $('#StrautoDoc').val(txtVal);
            });
});
```

but this was overwriting the current text I have generated via C#, which has information I am pulling from a database.

C# string I'm generating:

```
StrautoDoc.Text = DateTime.Now.ToString("MM/dd/yy") + " - " + GetUserName() + " assigned " + [user input for the task summary] + " to " [person being assigned the task];
```

This C# file is synced with a .aspx file where 'txtInstructions' (an

E.g.

```
private string GetTaskSummary()
{
    tbltask currentTask = new tblTask(); 
    currentTask.Instructions = txtInstructions.Text;
    if (currentTask != string.Empty)
    {
        currentTask.Instructions = Convert.ToString(txtInstructions.Text);
    }
     return currentTask; 
}
```

'tblTask' & 'Instructions' are from a db. But nothing seems to work, I was wondering what I am doing wrong, and what I can do to get this to work properly. Thanks in advance!

Comment: $('#StrautoDoc').append(txtVal); ? Hard to tell without seeing your HTML form.

Answer (score 0):

You need to rethink your whole approach. ASP.NET was created so that you do not have to work with HTML/JavaScript directly.

You can create the text boxes in your ASPX file as follows:

```
 <asp:TextBox runat="server" ID="txtInstructions" OnTextChanged="txtInstructions_TextChanged" AutoPostBack="true" />
 <asp:TextBox runat="server" ID="StrautoDoc" />
```

The  in your code behind file, you can have the following:

```
       protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }

        protected void txtInstructions_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            StrautoDoc.Text = DateTime.Now.ToString("MM/dd/yy") + " - " + GetUserName() + " assigned " + txtInstructions.Text + " to  [person being assigned the task]";
        }

        private string GetUserName()
        {
           return "name";
        }
```

This works entirely in C# without you having to write any JavaScript as ASP.NET was intended. Is there any reason why you want to be using Jquery seeing that your entire problem can be solved in ASP.NET alone?

Comment: Only reason I used JQuery was to test it out, because it worked, it just over wrote the existing generated string, and there was other JQuery code for different things in that same file, so I just thought I’d give it a shot.  I’m fairly new to asp.net and c# as well.

Comment: If you want to learn ASP.NET then consider using ASP.NET only before adding Jquery so that you understand it fully. ASP.NET has events such as Page_Load and TextChanged events. These allow you to respond to situations like yours where when text in one text box has changed, you can do something else such as changing text on another text box or connecting to a database.